# working with 2D data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a dataset with columns 'Start Station' and 'End Station'
I am trying to make a new list where every element of a list contain 
one from 'Start Station' and one from 'End Station'.
after that find an element in a new list with maximum frequency

```
trip=[]          #making list
for i in range(len(df)):      #loop till end
    trip.append((df['Start Station'][i],df['End Station'][i]))     #adding pairs in new list
print(max(trip,key=trip.count))
```

problem: this code works fine in jupyter notebook but when i am trying somewhere else it displays error

```
error:
trip.append((df['Start Station'][i],df['End Station'][i]))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 601, in __getitem__
    result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2477, in get_value
    tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 98, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4404)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 106, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value (pandas/_libs/index.c:4087)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/_libs/index.c:5126)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 759, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:14031)
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 765, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item (pandas/_libs/hashtable.c:13975)
KeyError: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# using pandas iterrows
trip=[]          

for ix, row in df.iterrows():    
    trip.append((row['Start Station'], row['End Station']))     

print(max(trip,key=trip.count))
```